# Changing min date if i click the other date

Tags: javascript, php

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    CheckIn: <input type="date" name="datein" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); 
    if(!empty($_POST['datein']))
            {
                $get = $_POST['datein'];
            } ?>" max="2030-12-31">
    CheckOut: <input type="date" name="dateout" min="<?php echo $get; ?>" max="2030-12-31">
</form>
```

I know this is a wrong codes. But what i want is if i click the CheckIn date the `min` of a CheckOut will also change even when i click again and again the CheckIn. I think in javascript there is a solution here but i don't know how to construct the codes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working demo for you, with validation for `max`. Date should not be greater than `max`:

```js
$('input[name=datein]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() < $('input[name=dateout]').attr('max')) {
    console.log('Before: ' + $('input[name=dateout]').attr('min'));
    $('input[name=dateout]').attr('min', $(this).val());
    console.log('After: ' + $('input[name=dateout]').attr('min'));
  } else {
    console.log('Value greater than ' + $('input[name=dateout]').attr('max') + ' not allowed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
CheckIn: <input type="date" name="datein" min="" max="2030-12-31"> CheckOut: <input type="date" name="dateout" min="" max="2020-12-31">
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, something like:

```
$('input[name=datein]').change(function() {
   // TODO Validate the value
   $('input[name=dateout]').attr('min',$(this).val());
});
```

This sets the min value equal to the value of the `datein` control.

.prop may be better than .attr here, but I think either may work.